# Como rodar uma aplicação web no IIS sem hospedar o código fonte na máquina?

Tags: c#, html, .net, iis

Desenvolvi uma aplicação web (asp.net, c#, javascript , etc) para um cliente. A ideia é amadurecer essa aplicação, e transformar em um produto. A dúvida é, como posso rodar a minha aplicação web localmente, ou seja, pelo IIS, no servidor do cliente, sem deixar o código fonte na máquina? Existe alguma alternativa que não seja hospedar a aplicação em um site? Ou de "encapsular" o programa, como acontece com windows app?

Muito obrigado.

Comment: Você usou ASPX para a apresentação ou usou Razor?

Comment: O padrão do projeto é web-forms, e não MVC. Eu estou usando o máximo de html5! E tags asp.net apenas quando necessário.  Abraços.

Answer (score 3):

Normalmente em Deploy tudo vai compilado, exceto os ASPX.

Para pré-compilar seu ASPX, faça o seguinte:

- Botão direito no projeto > Propriedades;
- Em *Post-build event command line*, coloque o comando:

  ```
  %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe -v / -p "$(SolutionDir)$(ProjectName)"
  ```

Funciona para o *framework* 4.0 do .NET.

Ao realizar *Build* do seu site, os arquivos ASPX sofrerão pré-compilação e não serão mais legíveis.

Comment: Eu tentei compilar (ctrl+shift+b) : %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe -v / -p "$C:\projetos\[pasta com a solution .sln]$[nome da solution]"
Mas ele da sempre o erro: '$C:\out\[pasta com a solution .sln]$[nome da solution]' is not a valid path. 
Se eu rodo sem os sinais de $, e sem a ultima parte $[nome da solution], ele compila, mas nada acontece.

Comment: Você copiou e colou exatamente o que eu postei na resposta?

Comment: Pensei que eram pra subistituir pelo caminho rs. Rodei como você postou, ele compilou, mas nada aconteceu.Eu consigo abrir os arquivos como texto ou pelo VS normalmente.

Comment: @AndréM Não gerou arquivos com a extensão `.compiled`?

Comment: CiganoMorrisonMendez Não gerou.

Comment: @AndréM Você fez apenas um Debug? Ou fez um Publish completo?

Comment: Apenas fiz o build como você falou. Botão direito no nome do projeto - Build Solution.

Comment: [Tirei a informação daqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398860.aspx). Não sei mais o que pode estar errado.